# .htaccess RewriteCond doesn't exclude

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a subdirectory on my localhost

In there there is a .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /buyback/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/static/*$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php
```

All the other functions are working just the RewriteCond is not working

index.php has a code

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/js/modal.js"></script>
```

which dosen't load. And I can't seem to grasp what the problem is.

Comment: What is an example of a url for which you expect the script to load and it is not loading? When you look at the source of the web page, the script code is not there?

Comment: http://localhost/buyback/static/js/modal.js  i removed / in src="/static/js/modal.js"> but it still isn't working... it's just normal index.php source code   and when i try to go to that link it gives me 404

Comment: So in in the `buyback` folder, any url that doesn't start with `static` gets redirected to index.php... To test it, you would need to test a url like `localhost/buyback/notstatic/blah`... That should redirect to index.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to **skip all files/directories from your rewrite**:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /buyback/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule !^static/ index.php [L,NC]
```

Your JS file's links should be:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/buyback/static/js/modal.js"></script>
```